# What is the difference between cross platform app development and hybrid app development?

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform, hybrid-mobile-app

I would like to know what exactly is the difference between cross platform app development and hybrid app development. I found different opinions while googling, majority says that the cross platform and hybrid app development are same and some [says its not !](http://www.program-ace.com/press-room/articles/native-cross-platform-hybrid-for-mobile)

Comment: mostly they are the same IMO.

Answer (score 5):

Hi You can see there are three technologies, Currently people used for development of the application. **Native, cross and hybrid platform technology.**

In short the Native is what pure stock application. The benefit of native application is you can directly interact with the native component of the operating system. You application user interface feel the part of operating system. because you used the native component instead of html component.
The cons of native application development is that, For example If you choose the native app development and you want to give the support in another platform i.e iOS, Window. In each platform you have to develop the application from scratch.

While in case of cross platform application develop using HTML and CSS component. There are lots of cross platform framework available. You can use it this framework provide you the access of the native API using HTML control. 
This options will help when if you are web developer and still you want to make the mobile application quick and faster way then you can suppose to choose this options. The another benefit is that the same application can run in other platform by single click compile the same application.

For the Hybrid app development We can say this is the combination of Native with Web Component development.I want to explain you the example. Let's say if you have screen that content the feeding concepts. Then it must be the quick, fast and easily get the feeds data from server to the user hand. So that quite difficult to mange into the Native environment. For that reason people are choose the Hybrid in which the portion of the screen is mixing with the native and html component. So in this example the feeding potions is consider as the HTML and CSS . Still the user interface of the screen I means the options and menu everything it is use native part.

This is what the difference. Actually It is dependent how you want to develop the application. What is the goal of your application. The kind of target users for the application.

Let me know if you need more information.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Hybrid**: A mix of native and "cross platform" elements, for example [native navigation controllers and web content](https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3743-hybrid-sweet-spot-native-navigation-web-content)

**Cross platform**: Develop in one place, compile/build to multiple platforms, for example: Apache Cordova (write html/css/js, build to multiplatform)

I would guess that the terms are thrown around interchangeably, and are not mutually exclusive. For example, the cordova build uses each platforms web-view controller, and therefore technically is hybrid apps

Answer (score 2):

Cross-platform application development is the process of creating the codebase once, and then compiling it for different mobile operating systems.Using this approach, the most important advantage is that the developers write the code only once and don't have to repeat or foster the code for execution on other operating systems.

Hybrid mobile applications also result in the same output and process. But the difference lies in how powerful and flexible are the development techniques that each of them uses. Hybrid development platforms involve using **HTML5 and Javascript**, which are **web** technologies. On the other hand, the cross development platforms can also include non-web technologies, like .NET Framewok-oriented ones, like Xamarin.
Consequently, hybrid mobile development refers to usage of web technologies and languages, while cross-platform also include non-web and standalone tools.
Some of the most widely-applied tools in cross and hybrid development are : Cordova, Phonegap, AppCelerator, Xamarin, by which the latter is currently the most powerful and almost-native one.

Answer (score 0):

**Cross Platform** technologies allow to execute some programs in different platforms. Best example is HTML/JS that works on almost all platforms, mobile included in our case. An example is apache cordova

The difference with **Hybrid** technologies is that hybrid programs are, in most cases, a combination of native and cross platform elements. Some examples are [react-native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/), [aj-framework](https://github.com/bfortunato/aj-framework), xamarin

I hope that this will help you. Bye

Answer (score 0):

Let me clear the dust.

Cross-Platform app development means that the app is developed using such a technology/language/framework whose end result i.e. an app can be used on different platforms like android, ios, windows, mac os, Linux, etc. An example of such framework/technology/library is React-Native, apps developed using React-Native can run on android and ios.

However, hybrid app development means that the app is developed using more than one language/technology but that does not always mean it will be cross-platform. For example, one can use both objective-c and swift in single ios app, both languages talk with each other by using a bridge.

Similarly, apps can be hybrid+cross_platform, an example for this can be, an app build using React-Native and a native platform language(android: java/Kotlin, iOS: swift/objective-c). Real world example of such apps can be [seen here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/showcase.html).

Answer (score 0):

- So native uses only native technologies.
- Hybrid ones, combines many
  technologies or languages like web ones and native one or may be (two
  others)
- Cross platoform is more about the result applications, more
  precisely the deployment possibilities which says that the
  applications could be deploy on many vendor devices.